# passing soap envelope in Python works on urllib but not on requests

Tags: python, soap, http-headers

I'm passing a soap envelope in Python2 with urllib and it works fine, but upon upgrading to Python3 and requests, the transaction fails. The specific error on the failure is, "The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported." Here are the content/commands for each:

## Python2/urllib

```
request = urllib2.Request(self._url, xml, request_headers)
```

### contents of each variable

**self._url:**

https://cert.api2.heartlandportico.com/Hps.Exchange.PosGateway/PosGatewayService.asmx?wsdl

**xml**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soap:Body><PosRequest xmlns="http://Hps.Exchange.PosGateway"><Ver1.0><Header><SecretAPIKey>skapi_cert_MYl2AQAowiQxxxxxxxizOP2jcX9BrEMqQ</SecretAPIKey><DeveloperID>000000</DeveloperID><VersionNbr>0000</VersionNbr></Header><Transaction><CreditSale><Block1><AllowDup>Y</AllowDup><AllowPartialAuth>N</AllowPartialAuth><Amt>1.15</Amt><CardHolderData><CardHolderFirstName>evan</CardHolderFirstName><CardHolderLastName>stone</CardHolderLastName><CardHolderPhone>9405947406</CardHolderPhone><CardHolderAddr>417 Neverland</CardHolderAddr><CardHolderCity>Denton</CardHolderCity><CardHolderState>TX</CardHolderState><CardHolderZip>76209</CardHolderZip></CardHolderData><CardData><TokenData><TokenValue>supt_kMKxxxxxxQacvPDvZNa</TokenValue><CardPresent>N</CardPresent><ReaderPresent>N</ReaderPresent></TokenData><TokenRequest>N</TokenRequest></CardData></Block1></CreditSale></Transaction></Ver1.0></PosRequest></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

**request_headers**

```
{'Content-length': '1110', 'Content-type': 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8'}
```

## Python3/requests

```
request = requests.post(self._url, xml, request_headers)
```

### contents of each variable

(identical as above)

## Note:

The actual request.headers.headers (which shows the *sent* headers) in Python3/requests make it look as if my headers dict was totally ignored, except for that one variable regarding length:

```
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.10.0', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Content-Length': '1110', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

In Python2/urllib, the output of request.headers is precisely as I sent it (see below), which makes me think there something going on within requests that is changing my headers and that's what is screwing everything up. Thoughts? Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
{'Content-length': '1110', 'Content-type': 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow... I figured it out as soon as I posted my question: apparently headers cannot simply be a positional argument in requests like they can in urllib--you have to specify `headers=` and voila!

I changed this: `request = requests.post(self._url, xml, request_headers)`

to this: `request = requests.post(self._url, xml, headers=request_headers)`

And it just WORKED.